# Impact on performance with require node.js module in individual functions versus globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have a node.js file with several functions. Suppose each of this function require the underscore module. What is the impact on performance of adding `var underS = require("underscore");` in each and every function versus declaring a single `var underS = require("underscore");` globally at the top? Which is better performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

So basically no, it'll not impact the performence.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add a generalized answer on top of a precise one.

***Never let performance impact the broad organization of your codebase, unless you seriously have a good (measured) reason not to.***

"Measured" in this context doesn't mean some micro-benchmark. It means profiled in the context of your actual project.

Ignoring this rule early on in my career bit me hard. It didn't aid me in writing efficient code, it simply diminished productivity to a minimum by making my codebase difficult to maintain, and difficult to stay in love with (a motivating human quality I think is often neglected to be mentioned).

So on top of the "no", you shouldn't worry about the performance of importing modules, I would suggest even more strongly, "no", you shouldn't worry about it anyway even if it did impact performance.

If you want to design for performance, performance-critical loopy code tends to make up a very small fraction of a codebase. It's tempting to think of it as a bunch of teeny inefficiencies accumulating to produce a bottleneck, but getting in the habit of profiling will quickly eliminate that superstition. In that little teeny section of your codebase, you might get very elaborate, maybe even implementing some of it in native code. And there, for this little teeny section of your codebase, you might study computer architecture, data-oriented design for cache locality, SIMD, etc. You can get extremely elaborate optimizing that little section of code which actually constitutes a profiling hotspot.

But the key to computational speed is first your own developer speed at producing and maintaining code efficiently by zooming out and focusing on more important priorities. That's what buys you time to zoom in on those little parts that actually do constitute measured hotspots, and affords you the time to optimize them as much as you want. First and foremost is productivity, and this is coming from one working in a field where competitive performance is often one of the sought-out qualities (mesh processing, raytracing, image processing, etc).